# Trying to read my database users details it prints out as an optional value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Trying to retrieve users from firebase and it is not possible stating an error that its returning an optional value , the code has been attached below.
I've added the debugger message below as well.

**code**

```
var ref = FIRDatabaseReference.init()

@IBOutlet weak var points: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var currentUser: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

func setupProfile(){
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let username1 = dictionary["username"] as! String
            print(username1)
            self.username.text = username1//Error is caused on this line EXC_BAD_Instruction
            //   ( code= EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode = 0x0)

        } 

    })
}
```

> Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist Snap (fpzfqMTapNel8F90q8bEO450eYg1) {
>       email = "abcd@test.com";
>       points = 100;
>       username = abcd;     } fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) }

Comment: Learn how Optionals work, it's very well explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: Thank you Eric for your quick response , but unfortunately ive been on that page already before , trying to understand the mistake here that ive made. and ive tried multiple ways. But it still keeps showing the same error :( .

Comment: ok. Then lets try to narrow down the scope of your question a little bit. What I mean is, you should remove from the question the code that is not relevant to it, that way it might be easier for people to see what's wrong. You should also point which line causes the crash - and check what are the values in the debugger when it does crash.

Comment: In setupProfile method why you have put ? after String?
remove that and try

Comment: Removing the ? After String still doesnt work , ive tried that already

Comment: Mr Eric ive narrowed down the coding and ive listed the debugger information please let me know what you think

Comment: @ZahidAhmed `self.currentUser.text = dictionary["username"] as! String?` is wrong. It should be `if let u = dictionary["username"] as? String { self.currentUser.text = u } else { // handle the error }`

Comment: Can you print out the output for `dictionary` inside `if  let dictionary`

Comment: @EricAya ive tried the code you suggested but it still seems to show Optional Value as the error

Comment: Don't just try my example, it's just a quick example, what you have to do is to *understand what's happening*. You were forcing the downcast with `as!` and it crashed because the value was nil. Now I've told you to safely unwrap instead. If you don't understand how this works, then please read the [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) chapter in the Swift book.

Comment: @muazhud INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
Snap (fpzfqMTapNel8F90q8bEO450eYg1) {
    email = "abcd@test.com";
    points = 100;
    username = abcd;
}
abcd
Snap (fpzfqMTapNel8F90q8bEO450eYg1) {
    email = "abcd@test.com";
    points = 100;
    username = abcd;
}
abcd
Snap (fpzfqMTapNel8F90q8bEO450eYg1) {
    email = "abcd@test.com";
    points = 100;
    username = abcd;
}
abcd
Snap (fpzfqMTapNel8F90q8bEO450eYg1) {
    email = "abcd@test.com";
    points = 100;
    username = abcd;
}
abcd

Comment: Please don't post code or structures in comments as they are impossible to read. Instead, update your question with the additional info.

Comment: @ZahidAhmed   `if let value = snapshot as? [String: AnyObject] {
    if let username = value["username"] as? String {
        print("Success getting username: \(username)")
    } else {
        print("Failed")
    }
  }` Please try use this code inside the closure.

Comment: Thank you @muazhad for the reply , your code works perfectly but it still does not solve the error of returning an optional value when i implement it to the variable with self.user.text = username to display it as a label.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: the code is malformed and open to crashes in the case of nil values within the snapshot. i.e. that would mean, for example, you try to access the key 'username' within the snapshot.value (as a dictionary) but the 'username' key doesn't exist.

Here's some suggested code with two options

```
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

         //make sure dict is available before proceeding
         if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

              //this is a test in response to a comment
              let email = dictionary["email"] as! String
              print(email)
              self.user.text = email

              ///if you are sure the 'username' key will always exist (neve
              let username = dictionary["username"] as! String
              print(username)
              self.user.text = username

              //if you are unsure if the 'username' will exist or not, protect your code!
              if let username = dict["username"] as? String {
                   //do something with username
              }
         } 

    })
```

To go along with the comments, understanding optionals is key to working with Swift and protecting your code (and users).

There are other options as well to protect your code but try this first.

Comment: Thank you so Much @Jay for the amazing response , the problem here is that it actually prints the username if i assign the value to it in the debugger, but while assigning self.user.text = username for example it gives out an error saying unexpected value that its an optional value.

Comment: @ZahidAhmed The issue is that there are too many variables here (not in code), so we need to isolate where there issue is. I changed the answer a little to help with isolating the problem. Try what I did and see if it still errors.

Comment: The change you made is exactly what i tried before finalizing that the error still persists. :( . i have no clue on what would be the issue here. but thank you so much for helping me with this.

Comment: @ZahidAhmed Does username print and the error occurs on the next line? The code in my answer works as long as the user class object has it's vars set up correctly.

Comment: Exactly the username prints , and the error happens in the next line.The vars have been set up correctly too

Comment: @ZahidAhmed Well, I duplicated your code and it's working here. One thing I noticed is that if you look closely at the error, you'll see the email in the snapshot is quoted *email = "abcd@test.com"* but the username, abcd is not *username = abcd*. As a test, try changing your code to read the email address and assign that to self.user.text. I updated the answer so you could see what I mean.

Comment: i dont know how it works for you . but unfortunately for me it still seems as an error even if i try to assign it the email address. but thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @ZahidAhmed I hope you updated the code in your question as that's definitely an issue. Perhaps updating your question by adding your newly fixed code (with the '?''s removed etc) will help someone spot the problem.

Comment: @ZahidAhmed Just thought of something. After this line *let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid* add *print(uid)* and see if the result is nil.

Comment: the result isint nil , this is what it printed out Optional("T6MTtb8x81dQIz0KNffYBfudNZ53")